# Mitigate parasitic capacitance coupling

Tags: capacitance, decoupling-capacitor

First conceptually:

- Assume you placed two metal electrodes/tags on a fencer's body: one on the torso (large, the lamé), one in the hand (small, the guard).
- Equipped with a Capacitive Sensor located at the tip of the attacking fencer, you contact each of the target areas (electrodes/tags) in sequence and measure/calculate the capacitance obtained.
- Your goal is to identify which of the parts/electrodes have been touched from differing capacitances. You expect to read different values because both targets feature very different areas/sizes, shapes, locations, and physical characteristics. Indeed you can see a clear difference between touching the lame versus, for example, an area covered with clothing, or indeed direct contact with skin.

Figure 1.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK9GXb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- BUT... you obtain very similar values for the Lamé and the Guard: you were expecting larger values for the large electrode, and (slightly) lower values for the small electrode. This is confirmed with a DMM.

Q1- Is this due to parasitic capacitance coupling?

Q2- What are my options to mitigate the effect of coupling? (Connect one or both electrodes to GND, send some Signal DC/AC, through them, etc...).

Q3- I read that placing a capacitor between the lines will prevent DC but will allow AC to pass. Would adding this Cap solve this problem?

Figure 2.
[image]

[legend: Capacitance measurements in pF]

More background:

The full circuit (Figure 1.) is composed of a Target fencer and an Attacking fencer. Both fencers carry a weapon. A weapon has a guard and a blade. Both have three identified target areas (tags or electrodes, as above):

1) the target areas are:

- i) target 1: the "Lame", (a conductive metal jacket),
- ii) target 2: the weapon "Guard" (also metal, a metal shield protecting the hand from direct hits),
- iii) any other areas other than i) and ii) (i.e. clothing).

2) Each weapon is linked to a capacitive sensor (Oscillator, MCU) at the end of its tip. When the weapon tip is depressed (outside the scope of this post) the signal sensed at the end of the attacking weapon tip is conveyed to the MCU via the blade line, the capacitance is calculated and the system detects if a target area has been touched.

3) Power sources and Grounds of the two fencers systems are separated (critical). Both fencers stand on the ground. No particular return path to earth is set: target areas/electrodes are connected to their circuit (MCU, bluetooth, etc.). The circuits are DC powered and can be considered isolated from earth.

4) The purpose for sampling numerical capacitance values is only to differentiate between the three target areas: electrode1, electrode2, no electrode/clothing.

5) Figure 2 (above) shows the capacitance readings from contacting four separated target areas: Lame, guard, clothing, non-fencer (ground). Observe the very small difference in average deviation between touch 1 and 2: very similar capacitance levels are obtained suggesting capacitance coupling.

Since very little can be done at the signal level to increase the contrast between the two states, the option envisaged is to further differentiate the signal at inception.

(Note: Amplification via signal processing has been considered, yet amplifying two very similar signals barely solves the issue, notwithstanding the time consumption aspects which make this kind of solution unaffordable in this context).

Comment: ... measure the capacitance ... to *what*? Is the patient sitting on a grounded sheet? Grounded by a third electrode? Sitting on a dielectric chair and your reference is the ground conductors in the building's wiring? You need to show your full circuit, the full path that the measurement current takes. Are you trying to do capacitance tomography, or are you looking for simple numerical measurements? The two situations require different mitigations.

Comment: Hi @Neil_UK. Thanks for your remarks. My question was conceptual in its first delivery. I understand your remark and where you are coming from: this question cannot be answered conceptually. I have therefore completely reformated the post. Hopefully this helps to understand the background. Thank you.

Comment: @Neil_UK, may I please trouble you for some of the mitigation suggestions you hinted at in your comment above? No tomography here, as you can see, but at least conceptually, measuring capacitance (to ground?) either on the hand or the chest and avoiding (too much) coupling is the objective. Thanks

Comment: Now you've updated the question, most of the mitigations fall flat, because they're based on some degree of stability. With two fencers leaping about, I think you could call that fairly unstable. You might be better off with oscillators, or MCUs, putting different frequencies into the various targets, and detecting which frequency is strongest to figure out which one you've hit.